# Summing all the values of a function

Tags: functions

The following function
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 50, &0\leq x\leq10 \\ 10+6x-0.2x^2, & 10<x\leq30\end{array}\right.$$
gives me the number of products that are sold in the $x$-th day of a month.

How am I supposed to find the approximated total number of sold products in a month? Is there a easier way than not doing
$$f(0)+f(1)+f(2)+\ldots+f(29)+f(30)?$$

Comment: You could use an integral as an approximation, but it would be less accurate and not much faster than TheSilverDoe's exact answer

Comment: I suspect they just want you to take the integral of the function from 0 to 30. Depends on how accurate the value needs to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

$$\sum_{k=0}^{30} f(k)= \sum_{k=0}^{10} f(k) + \sum_{k=11}^{30} f(k) = \sum_{k=0}^{10} 50 + \sum_{k=11}^{30}(10 + 6k -0.2k^2)$$
$$=50 \times 11 + 10 \times 20 + 6 \left( \frac{30\times 31}{2} -\frac{10\times 11}{2} \right) - 0.2 \left(  \frac{30\times 31 \times 61}{6} -\frac{10\times 11 \times 21}{6} \right) = 1396$$

Comment: This is *exactly* doing $f(0)+f(1)+\dots+f(29)+f(30)$, and is an exact value, not an approximation.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the post :) I will delete my answer...

Comment: Don't. It's still a valid method. To the OP: this uses the summation formulas  $$\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac {n(n+1)}2 \text{ and } \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac {n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$$

Comment: Ok, I let the OP tell me if this answer is useful or not :)

Comment: This is not "exactly doing $f(0)+f(1)+...+f(30)$". You are not calculating each value and adding, which is what I presume the OP means. +1.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I'm mainly concerned (and confused) with the OP's word choice of "approximation", which suggests integration as an approximation technique may be what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe my exercises asks for a approximated value but I think this works, for sure! I mean, I don't have to calculate each value separately.

Comment: @player3236 how am I supposed to use integrals here?

Comment: To see the connection with integrals, sketch a bar chart for the month with the number sold on each day. Each bar has a width of 1. So the area of all the bars is the total number sold that month. Then also sketch the function itself. You can see the area under the function is "roughly" the area of all the bars. This is like a riemann sum with a bar width of 1. But rather than approximating an integral by a set of bars... we're doing the opposite here and approximating the sum of the bars by the integral.

Answer (score 2):

An approximation might be $$\int_{-0.5}^{10.5} 50 \,dx +  \int_{10.5}^{30.5} (10+6x-0.2x^2)\, dx$$ which would suggest $\frac{4187}{3} = 1396-\frac13$, so not far away